# Applying primefaces style outside <xsl:template match="/"> tags xls?

Tags: xml, xslt, primefaces, xslt-1.0

I came across interesting thing is that applying the style outside `<xsl:template match="/">` here is the scenario

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
        <ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
        xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
        template="/WEB-INF/template.xhtml">
<ui:define name="content">
          <p:tabView scrollable="true">
            <p:tab title="My Report">
                <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="cd/title" />
                </h:panelGrid>
            </p:tab>


           </p:tabView> 
        </ui:define>
        </ui:composition>
</xsl:template>



<xsl:template match="messagetype">
 <p:panel header="Message Type">           **---->Trying to apply code for 
                                                 values it throws error p: is not bound**
   <span style="color:blue;">
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </span>
 </p:panel>
</xsl:template>
```

> If i define ui:compsition above `<xsl:template match="/">` it throws me error in xls
>
> I have lot of code i can't do nested now like having `<xsl:template match="messagetype">` inside `<xsl:template match="/">`

Comment: How is this PrimeFaces related other than the tags being in the xslt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the namespace declarations like `xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"` to the `xsl:stylesheet` element.